# Текст из визуального редактора WP на страницу

Tags: wordpress

Как вывести текст на кастомную страницу из визуального редактора WP?

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен что оптимальный вариант, зато работает) Итак, вставляем код (цикл while) в нужную часть нашей кастомной страницы:

```
<div class="content_editor">

        <?php
            while ( have_posts() ) :
                the_post();

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/custom-content', 'page' );

            endwhile;
            ?>

    </div>
```

Затем делаем новый файл - custom-content.php и в него вставляем следующий код:

" >

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php
    the_content( sprintf(
        wp_kses(
            __( 'Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'хххххх' ),
            array(
                'span' => array(
                    'class' => array(),
                ),
            )
        ),
        get_the_title()
    ) );

    wp_link_pages( array(
        'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'ххххх' ),
        'after'  => '</div>',
    ) );
    ?>
</div>
```

ххххх - название вашей темы (код взят из файла content.php) там можно посмотреть данное название

Comment: А в чём суть? В использовании основополагающей функции the_content() ? Ну да, она выведет контент любого поста.